# Dojo grid implementation in zend fremawork,

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Guys

I tried to follow this tutorial http://www.encodez.com/blog/zend-dojo-data-grid-json.html but I keep recieving java script error

```
xhrFailed
[Break On This Error]   

return mix(new Error(error), {src:"dojoLoader", info:info});
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this issue any idea.